# Работа с списками в Python

Tags: python

```
lst = [1,34,563,2,6,3]
for i in range(1, 10):
    random.choice(lst)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы элемент списка нельзя было выбрать 2 раза подряд. Например, выпал элемент "34", нужно сделать так, его нельзя было выбрать 2 раза подряд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сохраняйте старое значение и генерируйте новое, пока они не будут отличаться:

```py
import random
lst = [1,34,563,2,6,3]
prev = None
el = None
for i in range(1, 10):
    while prev == el:
        el = random.choice(lst)
    print(el)
    prev = el
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант. Он лучше тем, что в нём нет возможности попасть в бесконечный цикл и время его выполнения будет предсказуемо.

```py
import random

lst = [1, 34, 563, 2, 6, 3]
prev = None

for _ in range(100):
  number = random.choice(lst)
  lst.remove(number)

  if prev is not None:
    lst.append(prev)
  prev = number

  print(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто исключать индекс последнего элемента из диапазона генерации. Лишних проверок и тасований списка нет.

```
lst = [1,34,563,2,6,3]
n = len(lst)
last = random.randint(0, n - 1)
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(lst[last])
    last = (last + random.randint(1, n - 1)) % n
```